# Python Dice Game Points Variables Not Changing

Tags: python, function, dice

```
rounds = input()

for i in range(int(rounds)):
    score = input(int())[0:3]
    a = score[0]
    d = score[2]


antonia = 100
david = 100

for scores in score:

    if a < d:
        antonia -= int(a)
    if a > d:
        david -= int(d)
    elif a == d:
        pass

print(antonia)
print(david)
```

**Input Expectation:**
The first line of input contains the integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 15), which is the number of rounds that
will be played. On each of the next n lines, will be two integers: the roll of Antonia for that round,
followed by a space, followed by the roll of David for that round. Each roll will be an integer
between 1 and 6 (inclusive).

**Output Expectation:** The output will consist of two lines. On the first line, output the number of points that Antonia has
after all rounds have been played. On the second line, output the number of points that David has
after all rounds have been played.

Input:

1. 4
2. 5 6
3. 6 6
4. 4 3
5. 5 2

Output:

- 100 <--(WHY???)
- 94

***Why is the bottom value(david) changed as it should correctly, but the top is not?? What am I doing different for antonia thats making it not output the same function as david?***

Comment: In the second loop you're iterating over `score`, but `a` and `d` are never changed. They keep the _last value from the first loop_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your first loop, you continuously update `a` and `d`. So, at the end of the loop, `a` and `d` simply have the values corresponding to the last set of input.

Additionally, within your second loop, you are not iterating over all the scores, but rather the very last set of input. Before going any further, I would suggest you go back and understand what exactly your code is doing and trace how values change.

In any case, one way to solve your problem is:

```
rounds = input("Number of rounds: ")
scores = []
for i in range(int(rounds)):
    score = input("Scores separated by a space: ").split()
    scores.append((int(score[0]), int(score[1]))) #Append pairs of scores to a list

antonia = 100
david = 100

for score in scores:
    a,d = score # Split the pair into a and d
    if a < d:
        antonia -= int(a)
    if a > d:
        david -= int(d)
    elif a == d:
        pass

print(antonia)
print(david)
```